# Can I set an expectancy on should_receive and have it execute the original code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have something like:

```
value = nil

if some_condition
  value =my_object.do_stuff()
end
```

And in my test, I have the follwing:

```
MyObject.any_instance.should_receive(:do_stuff)
```

However, I'd like to just test that the method was called, and have it execute the original code. I'd like to NOT have to do it like:

```
MyObject.any_instance.should_receive(:do_stuff).and_return(:some_dummy_value)
```

Is there a way of doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is `and_call_original` method:

```
MyObject.any_instance.should_receive(:do_stuff).and_call_original
```

See https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks#delegating-to-the-original-implementation

Answer (score 0):

I believe, that it's better to create object by FactoryGirl and than to test it. You can read how to make [factories](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl) and so on.
Example:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :my_object do
   [*here is your attributes*]
  end
end
```

So, after you created a factory, you should to create test where this method used and write this:

```
my_object = FactoryGirl.create(:my_object)
my_object.should_receive(:do_stuff)
```

Inside your code you will do that "do_stuff" with your "my_object" when u will run test.